# How to extend plugins into my theme directory or customize plugin without touching the core files in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, extends

I would like to know if there was any methodologies to inherit or extend a plugin files to theme directory as woocommerce did and customize them without touching the base/core files. please share any links or thoughts

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for WordPress's [add_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) and [do_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) functions. WooCommerce, for example, makes use of these functions by using [hooks and filters for templates and functions](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/).

For example, WooCommerce does things like `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );`. This means that you can "add and action", override functionality, remove actions, and generally customize things how you see fit.

Not all plugins and themes ship with this functionality; but browsing the source code can often reveal instances of this. It's more of a courtesy by developers.

Comment: Well said, I found only similar answers through out the web. Is there any options that forcefully take in charge with plugin names ? other than these action hooks (even if there is no class to extend).